# Access variable outside stream callback function - Javascript, WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm streaming a webcam, and want a method to stop the webcam. I'm trying to stop it by calling stop on the streaming track, altough I can't reach the track variable outside the callback function. How do I access track in this function outside the callback-function? Basically like this:

```
var track;
            function successCallback(stream) {
                localstream = stream; // stream available to console
                track = stream.getTracks()[0];
                if (window.URL) {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                } else {
                    video.src = stream;
                }
            }
track.stop();
```

The complete instance looks like this:

```
function media(i) {
            navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

            var constraints = {
                audio: false,
                video: true
            };
            var video = document.querySelectorAll("video")[i];
            var localstream;

            function successCallback(stream) {
                localstream = stream; // stream available to console
                var track = stream.getTracks()[0];
                if (window.URL) {
                    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                } else {
                    video.src = stream;
                }

                track.stop();
            }

            function errorCallback(error) {
                console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
            }

            navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
        }
```

Comment: You can't if `successCallback` is called in an asynchronous operation. Please provide more code context related to use of the callback and a better explanation of what you need to accomplish. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: What is expected result of calling `track.stop()`?

Comment: To stop the webcam from streaming. Will update the question!

Comment: @Jesper The `javascript` at updated Question is different from original `javascript` at Question? `track` is not defined as a variable outside of `media` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `track` outside scope of `media` function. Also, consider revoking the `Blob URL` set at `video` `src` when `track.stop()` is called.

```
window.onload = function() {
  let track, url;

  function media(i) {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

    var constraints = {
      audio: false,
      video: true
    };
    var video = document.querySelectorAll("video")[i];
    var localstream;

    function successCallback(stream) {
      localstream = stream; // stream available to console
      track = stream.getTracks()[0];
      if (window.URL) {
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.src = url;
      } else {
        video.src = stream;
      }

      // track.stop();
    }

    function errorCallback(error) {
      console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
    }

    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, successCallback, errorCallback);
  }

  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  button.onclick = function() {
    track.stop();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    // document.querySelectorAll("video")[i].src = "";
  }
  media(0)
}
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/FJhEBOCTRcE5NUUaEI7B?p=preview